# Is there a search/find event in browsers?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm in the middle of building a not scrollable, fixed layout website, but as usual, non conventional websites tend to have shortages. There is a scrollable news element in the page, which scrolls a div container's div childs up and down by the mousewheel. The problem arises, when someone tries to search in the page, pressing CTRL+F and the content is out of the viewport (not scrolled into view). Is there any common event, which handles the find/search inside browsers?

Comment: "THE" problem arises? Which problem is that?

Comment: Not that I know of. You can track the key events although and check if it was Ctrl+F.

Comment: @Jauzsika from here http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/ , i would conclude a big NO. But you would simulate it using combination of `blur,keydown,submit` please correct if wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not completely certain about this, but I dont think DOM has any events that fire when a uses searches and that it a browser function that you can not hook on.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOM_events